# Best approach to detect people in a STATIC camera images ( not using video stream ) - HOG, Haar, BackgroundSubtract in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, background-subtraction, haar-classifier

So I am planning on implementing human detection static camera images - the camera never moves but the lighting conditions do change. Humans can be upright or could be sitting.

**Question:**

**What would be better in this case to detect people in such setup?**

**Haarcascade** mostly deals with faces and eyes and my images are taken from an angle where these features are extremely hard to detect especially for people with their backs toward the camera.

**HOG features** - I am not sure on this one

**backgroundSubtractorMOG**- does not seem to provide a very good result now even using a lot of images to "run through the subtractor" to build the background

Sample image with no people in it:
[image]

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108264/c-opencv-tracking-moving-people-on-the-street? Does the fact the camera is static make this question really different?

Comment: even if the camera is not moving, we're still talking about a video feed here.

Comment: What I meant is that I am snapping images say every 30 seconds, and I am not actually capturing a video feed.

Comment: also, background-subtraction won't detect humans, but it will be a good help at finding spots with movement (so you won't have to scan the whole pic each time)

Comment: HoG works quite ok for standing people. Probably not for sitting ones though. Background subtraction will work... until the chairs have moved and arent added to background :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be easier to detect anything that moves on a picture? Detecting body, that can be in different positions would be very difficult (especially if half of the body is hidden behind a table). I'm writing face detection algorithm using Haarcascade at the moment - it can deal with any type of shape (not only face and eyes), but it must find some common features between those objects - bodies can vary a lot in colours, shapes and positions. It would also be difficult to make a cascade for that (you'll need thousands of sample images)

If camera is static, the only things that move would be humans. Utilize that fact. I don't have experience in that matter, but this place may give you a hint: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10248/Motion-Detection-Algorithms